# how to authenticate to a Cloud Run service with a specific service account (not the one that executes the code) from Python?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, access-token, google-cloud-run

In case to make a request, the caller must have a token that will be passed in the header.

---

One question is what kind of token should it be (ID or Access) and how to get it for a specific service account (not the one which executes the code).

In case to get an Access token, a deprecated Google library should be used, there is apparently on other way of getting it from Python code.

Another option is ID token, but it is unclear how to get it for a specific service account.

The same applies to the usage of Metadata server, it can supposedly provide Access token but it is unclear how to make request to it with a specific service account.

Some articles say that conceptually it should be Access token, but Google manual says otherwise. And indeed:

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://[...]-uc.a.run.app/[...] # doesn't work

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token --audiences=https://[...]-uc.a.run.app)" https://[...]-uc.a.run.app/[...] # does work
```

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service

So apparently it has to be an ID token. It has to be created for a specific audience, i.e. a specific host (without path) of the service the token is intended for.

---

Now, the main question is how to get it for a service account other than the one executing the Python code.

The key of the service account in question is being retrieved from Google Secret Manager, as I am not willing to store it as a file anywhere.

When using the approach suggested in `google-auth` sample code -

```py
client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/latest"
response = client.access_secret_version(name=name)
secret = response.payload.data.decode('UTF-8')
info = json.loads(secret)
credentials = service_account.IDTokenCredentials.from_service_account_info(info, target_audience=target_audience)
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(request)
token = credentials.token
```

I am getting this error in `service_account.IDTokenCredentials.from_service_account_info` -

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid JWT Signature.'})
```

Comment: Google Cloud Run authorization requires an OIDC Identity Token with the `aud` (audience) set to the Cloud Run service URL. All of the SDKs support generating the required token.

Comment: @JohnHanley yes this is what the linked article says, the problem is how to get this token for a service account retrieved from secret manager and not the one running the code.

Comment: After your last edit. The parameter `info` must be incorrect. The contents should be from a service account JSON file. What are you using? Show how you are reading that data and the data (redact the private key and private key ID). When posting code, provide enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added the secret retrieval part. The secret content is service account key in JSON format.